# What parts are really required to motorize 10219 Maersk Train?

Tags: power-functions, trains, set-modification

The [Official site detailed page](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Maersk-Train-10219) states that:

> Motorize your Maersk train by adding LEGO Power Functions #8878 Rechargeable Battery Box, #8887 Transformer 10V DC, #8884 IR Receiver, #8879 IR Speed Remote Control and #88002 Train Motor!

So:

```
8878
8887
8884
8879
88002
```

Is it true that I need all of them (costs ~$150) to motorize the train, or can I omit some?

Comment: @Zhaph: Why `set-modification`? I don't modify anything. Just motorize a train, I'm sure it's not a modification, or this is a subject to discuss on meta, isn't it?

Comment: Seems to be the preferred use; from the wiki for the tag: "Set Modification questions are about modifying sets produced by LEGO. Modifications include Motorising existing sets" but yes happy to discuss on meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The strict minimum you need for PF motorization is:

- [Tracks](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7896-1). Sounds obvious, but don't forget these. Nope, there are none with the Maersk train.
- [A PF train motor](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=88002-1)
- [A PF battery box](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=88000-1) (plus 6 AAA batteries)

Now, as oezi [says](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/815), it's a bit senseless to have a train which you can't control. Well, you **can** control it, but it's limited to switching it on and off (if you can catch it). Yet, it's a start.

Now, as far as limited control goes, don't neglect the [polarity switch](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8869-1)! If you place it intelligently, it will be easier to stop your train. Or you could even mimic the old 4,5v system and have your train switch direction automatically at both ends of a track. Just a thought.

Of course, for more serious control, yes, you'll need:

- [PF IR receiver](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8884-1)
- [PF IR speed remote control](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8879-1)

Note that all these elements (tracks, motor, battery box, IR receiver and remote) are also present in these trains:

- [Passenger Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7938-1)
- [Cargo Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7939-1)
- [Red Cargo Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3677-1) (red battery box)

So it may be worth to do the math and see if you're not better off just buying one of these. Sets are usually cheaper than standalone elements, and considering the extra parts you'll get, it may be a wiser investment. Not to mention that they may be easier to find in regular shops, which means maybe Christmas discounts and the like. And the design of these trains is quite good too.

Of course, batteries are going to be a problem, so if you don't want to sink too much money in them you'd better use rechargeable batteries as fast as possible, or yes, switch to:

- [PF Rechargeable Battery](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=8878-1)
- [10VDC transofmer](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8887-1) - or [use a cheaper one](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/794)

As you can see, it can be a costly investment in the long run, but nothing forces you to buy it all in one step, especially the rechargeable battery and charger which are far from cheap.

Comment: I did this mod last night. The train motor is about $14, the battery box $13, the IR receiver $15. Assuming you have a remote control ($13) and batteries, you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

The transformer can be omitted, if you find a suitable, cheaper one. Take a look at [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/794/17) for more information about the exact requirements.

I don't think the other parts can be omitted, as...

- A motor clearly is required to motorize something (#88002)
- A motor won't work without a battery (#8878)
- Something motorized that can't be controlled is senseless (#8879 & #8884)

In addition, you could try to buy these 4 parts on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/), which is a bit cheaper, so you end at ~$105 (+ ~$10 for a third party transformer) - this should save you $35 (~25%).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the rechargeable battery box and that's the most expensive part. Get the AAA battery box and use your own rechargeable batteries.

$13 [88000](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-AAA-Battery-Box-88000) AAA Battery box

$14 [88002](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Train-Motor-88002) Train Motor

$13 [8879](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-IR-Speed-Remote-Control-8879) IR Speed Remote

$15 [8884](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-IR-Receiver-8884) IR Receiver

That's about $55. Not cheap but not over the top. You'll also need tracks but even on a set you're going to need to spring for more tracks if you want it to be awesome.